# need help applying filter to php echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type in Wordpress. The visual editor shows paragraph breaks, but when viewing the post these breaks disappear, unlike in regular posts.

This is my content code in the single-custompostype.php file:

```
 <?php echo $content = get_the_content(); ?>
```

I read that I should add this to it:

```
$content = apply_filters("the_content",$post->post_content);
```

But when I add it like so, there's no effect:

```
<?php $content = apply_filters("the_content",$post->post_content); echo $content = get_the_content(); ?>
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: just `echo $content` in your last line maybe?

Comment: You've overwriting your *filtered* `$content` variable with the second statement; remove the last `echo $content = get_the_content();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following solve it for you? It seems like you are getting `$content` right, then overwrite it...

```
<?php 
  $content = apply_filters("the_content",$post->post_content); 
  echo $content; 
?>
```